# difference between Validation data and Testing data

Tags: python, validation, testing, deep-learning, neural-network

I am confused with the terms validation and testing, is validating the model same as testing it? is it possible to use testing data for validation?

what even confuses me more is that when to use validation? is it a necessary step for the model? also is it possible to do validation instead of testing?

also can you tell if this code does testing? it is really confusing me

```
model.fit_generator(
    training_gen(1000,25),
    steps_per_epoch=50,
    epochs=10000,
    validation_data=validation_gen(1000, 25),
    validation_steps=1,
    callbacks=[checkpoint],
    verbose=2)

model.load_weights('./temp_trained_25.h5')
BER = []
for SNR in range(5, 30, 5):
    y = model.evaluate(
        validation_gen(10000, SNR),
        steps=1
    )
    BER.append(y[1])
    print(y)
print(BER)
```

noting that training_gen and validation_gen are:

```
def training_gen(bs, SNRdb = 20):
    while True:
        index = np.random.choice(np.arange(train_size), size=bs)
        H_total = channel_train[index]
        input_samples = []
        input_labels = []
        for H in H_total:
            bits = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.5, size=(payloadBits_per_OFDM,))
            signal_output, para = ofdm_simulate(bits, H, SNRdb)
            input_labels.append(bits[0:16])
            input_samples.append(signal_output)
        yield (np.asarray(input_samples), np.asarray(input_labels))


def validation_gen(bs, SNRdb = 20):
    while True:
        index = np.random.choice(np.arange(train_size), size=bs)
        H_total = channel_train[index]
        input_samples = []
        input_labels = []
        for H in H_total:
            bits = np.random.binomial(n=1, p=0.5, size=(payloadBits_per_OFDM,))
            signal_output, para = ofdm_simulate(bits, H, SNRdb)
            input_labels.append(bits[0:16])
            input_samples.append(signal_output)
        yield (np.asarray(input_samples), np.asarray(input_labels))
```

I'm quite new to deep learning and it seems like everything confuses me, sorry if my questions seems dump and unreasonable but please if you can help me to figure out this confusion I would be thankful.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: With all modeling verification (testing) and validation are both important. Verification is making sure the code/model works as intended whereas Validation is making sure the model accurately reflects what it is meant to model. If your specific case is different then I don't know what else to tell you. My knowledge is general modeling.

Comment: This seems a better question for [datascience.se] as it doesn't pertain to the specifics of coding or programming. In general, if you search for "machine learning validation vs testing data", you get many many results. What _do_ you understand of the difference, and what _specific_ question to you need to clarify?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but I might ask another question. Is it possible during evaluation to only use validation data and not test data, I'm asking because I came across a code that does this thing and I can't seem to understand why. Thanks again! @EliHarold

Comment: @G.Anderson Thanks for your explanation, but I might ask another question. Is it possible during evaluation to only use validation data and not test data, I'm asking because I came across a code that does this thing and I can't seem to understand why. Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely possible to do no testing, just as it's technically possible to do no validation. You could just train a model and go straight to production if you wanted to. However, you can imagine reasons why this would be a bad idea, yes? Same as no-testing paradigms. You can, but whether you _should_ is a matter of opinion

Comment: @G.Anderson that helped a lot, thank you so much!!